# Make Class Inherit Styling From Another External Class

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to make a class inherit from another class (from a different CSS file)?

```
/* Make this class have all .form.control's styling. 
   form.control is located in a separate standard .css file*/
.token-input-list-facebook {
    .form-control;  
}
```

**Edit** Further information: The HTML element with the class 'token-input-list-facebook form-control' is dynamically generated by a third party library. An input gets turned into an input with a hidden `ul` that auto-suggests things. So I could go and edit the 3rd party javascript. But styling through stylesheets (CSS or LESS) is a more elegant method

Comment: Yes, you can [import the standard.css file as reference](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) and then invoke it.

Comment: You want to implement this in LESS?

Answer (score 0):

class="token-input-list-facebook form-control"

Comment: Can you please clarify what this would do? I mean add an explanation instead of just giving a one line code.

Comment: The HTML element with the class 'token-input-list-facebook form-control' is dynamically generated by a third party library. So I could go and edit the 3rd party javascript. But styling through stylesheets (CSS or LESS) is a more elegant method.